# Can Jquery Data table read differntly formatted json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I am using jQuery dataTables for grids (http://www.datatables.net/).

However my json is formatted differently than the json example included with dataTables docs. Is it possible for dataTables to interpret the formatting in our json?

Their json looks like this

```
 {"aaData": [
 [
  "Trident",
  "Internet Explorer 4.0",
  "Win 95+",
  "4",
  "X"
  ],
 [
  "Trident",
  "Internet Explorer 5.0",
  "Win 95+",
  "5",
  "C"
 ]  
 ]  
 }
```

My JSON looks like this and unfortunately I can't change it to look like the example included in their docs.

```
"allconfig": {
    "card.inserted": {
        "value": "Not Inserted",
        "type": "enum",
        "range": "",
        "clone": false,
        "archive": false,
        "access": "R"
    },
    "card.cisproc": {
        "value": "Processed",
        "type": "string",
        "range": "",
        "clone": false,
        "archive": false,
        "access": "R"
    }
    }
    }
```

Here is my jQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": 'json/test.json'
  });
   });
```

Comment: Sometimes yes, but usually no. I'd suggest formatting your json to match what is expected by the plugin, even if that means doing it with javascript after you receive it.

Comment: no idea how to that on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your json format to required format.

Use

```
  $.getJSON('json/test.json', function(data) {
  var newJson = [];
    var myJson = data ;
    $.each(myJson.allconfig, function (key, value) {
        var rowArray = [];
        rowArray.push(key);
        $.each(myJson.allconfig[key], function (key1, value1) {
            rowArray.push(value1);
        });
        newJson.push(rowArray);
    });
  $('#example').dataTable( { "bProcessing": true, "aaData":newJson  });
});
```

check http://jsfiddle.net/JASdL/

Comment: can var myJson = a location and file like this   myJson = $.getJSON('json/test.json', function(data) {
var items = [];

Comment: sorry, i didnt got your question on comment. can you elaborate it.

Comment: Currently my script to load the table with json looks like this                                                                                                                                         $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'json/test.json'
    } );
} );                                                                                                                                       How do I add your code to my code?

Comment: You cant assign it directly on variable because its a ajax call and it doesn't return value. Instead you can do it inside call back function like
$.getJSON('json/test.json', function(data) { var myJson =data ; ....

Comment: Im not sure what that means.

Comment: Yeah it kind of works now, WOW! Expect the main ID is not shown. If you look at my JSON code there is a hierarchy that reflects machine id ex:("card.inserted":  "card.cisproc": ) That should go into the fist column of the dataTable

Comment: you can push that also on array put rowArray.push(key) after var rowArray = [];